# Subspace of Linear Transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

*(Do not joke me please, I need help)*

$V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, $ = \{(_1, _2) \in \mathbb R^2: _1 + _2 = 0\}$ is defined.

a) $\dim (\mathbb R^2 ∩ )$

b) $\dim (\mathbb R^2 + )$

c) $\dim ( + )$

d) Are there injective linear transformations from $V$ to $\mathbb R^2$?

e) Are there injective linear transformations from $\mathbb R^2$ to $V$?

Comment: Why would anyone "joke you"? What some people would ask you to do is to present your own work and effort on solving these questions...like I do now.

Comment: Have you made any attempts with any of these questions? If you can could you edit your post with the work you've already done, otherwise you might not get too much help I'm afraid.

Comment: Why you people so selfish to helpless people?

Comment: No one is being selfish here except you.  You have presented the equivalent of a homework exercise here and asked that the community do it for you.  This is not the intention of this site.  Please edit your question in order to provide clarity, focus, and context.  What is your definition of dimension?  What is $X+Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces?  Where did you encounter this exercise?  At a minimum, what steps have you taken towards solving this problem, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Sheldon we're not being selfish. We want to help, not do everything for you. Just giving you the answers is at best a mistake born out of compassion and at worst actively hindering your development as a mathematician. Give the questions a go, come back with what you've attempted and we'll be happy to give you pointers on what you're stuck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the linear system that describes $V$ you get that $V=\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{v}:=\mathbf{e}_1-\mathbf{e}_2)$. From this follows that $\dim V=1$. Then

- $\dim(V \cap \mathbb{R}^2)=\dim(V)=1$
- $\dim(V + \mathbb{R}^2)=\dim(\mathbb{R}^2)=2$
- Do you really mean $V+V$?

Then by virtue of the rank-nullity thereom $$\dim D = \dim \ker f + \dim f(D) \text{,}$$ where $f$ is a linear map with domain $D$, you get

- You may have such a linear map
- Since $2>1$ you can't have an injective linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $V$

If you need more help, just ask.

Comment: thank you so much..